# Use $dir with backslashes escaped in VSCode settings

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, escaping, vscode-code-runner

I'm using the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) for [VSCode][2] *(Visual Studio Code)* and I'm trying to change the run command for `C++`.

I have the following setting in my settings.json file:

```
// Set the executor of each language.
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    // ...

    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"

    // ...
}
```

Then when I press `CTRL SHIFT P` and press enter on `Run Code` to run my current C++ file, it produces the following command to be ran:

```
cd "c:\C++\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\C++\"main
```

But then the output of the command is:

```
bash: cd: c:\C++" && g++ main.cpp -o main && c:C++"main: No such file or directory
```

This is because as you can see in the command being run, it's trying to CD to `"c:\C++\"` but the `\` characters are not being escaped and it causes the command to fail.
If the command had all the `\` characters escaped to look like `"c:\\C++\\"`, it would run correctly.

I am using the git bash console for my integrated terminal.

How can I fix this issue and escape the path's retreived from the `$dir` variable in my `settings.json` file?

Comment: How did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @tusharRawat Sorry I asked this in 2017, I cannot remember.

Answer (score 2):

Try out the $dirWithoutTrailingSlash variable instead of $dir.

If that doesn't work, you can try making your own variables in `codeManager.js` located in `%VSCODE_INSTALL%\Data\code\extensions\formulahendry.coderunner-%VERSION%\out\src\`.

Add entries to the `placeholders` array located near line # 246. For example:

```
{ regex: /\$dirWithoutQuotesNorTrailingSlash/g, replaceValue: this.getCodeFileDirWithoutTrailingSlash() }
```

which I used to replace

```
{ regex: /\$dirWithoutTrailingSlash/g, replaceValue: this.quoteFileName(this.getCodeFileDirWithoutTrailingSlash()) }
```

because I couldn't use variables with explicit quotes in classpaths.
You can also define your own function return values (like getCodeFileDirWithoutTrailingSlash) with regex right above it (circa line #222).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using make, it's more flexible that way, just create a `makefile` in the root folder with that content:

```
all:
    g++ main.cpp -o main.exe
    main.exe
```

Now you can run `all` target through the terminal by writing `make all` or just `make` (this will run the very first target which is `all`).

---

To quickly execute the target via code-runner, add this to settings.json:

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "make -s #", 
}
```

the `-s` flag stands for silently, i.e. do not output commands to the console, and `#` is a comment sign to comment out the path to the file that code-runner will add to the command.